# shelve archives not openable on other computer

Tags: python-3.x, shelve

I have saved some objects with shelve. In an other file I was able to restore these objects. But when I copy the archive to an other computer shelve gives me a `_gdbm.error: File read error`. The packages which hold the classes of the stored objects are directly accessible on both computers (but they are stored in different locations and added with PYTHONPATH). Both machines run on Ubuntu 13.10, one is 32bit and the other 64bit.

Shouldn't these archives be machine independent?

On the 64bit machine I get

```
>>> import shelve
>>> shelve.open('arch.db')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python3.3/shelve.py", line 232, in open
    return DbfilenameShelf(filename, flag, protocol, writeback)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.3/shelve.py", line 216, in __init__
    Shelf.__init__(self, dbm.open(filename, flag), protocol, writeback)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.3/dbm/__init__.py", line 94, in open
    return mod.open(file, flag, mode)
_gdbm.error: File read error
```

and on the 32bit machine it works.

When I create an archive on the 64bit machine, it is openable on the 32bit machine, but the interactive python prompt crashes:

```
>>> import shelve
>>> s = shelve.open('arch.db')
>>> for i in s.items(): print(i)
...
gdbm fatal: lseek error
```

I don't even get a traceback.

It is really annoying, I intended to work on both computers, but at the moment I am bound to my slow 32bit eeepc, because I've already saved a lot into the archive.

Comment: the files on both computers have the same md5sum

Comment: what happens if you try `shelve.open('arch')`? some dbm backends add the `.db` to the filename by default.

Comment: when I omit the extension, shelve does not find the file...

Comment: I have the same issue but the other way round (created on a 64bit machine with python 3.4.0 + python3-gdbm 3.4.3, lseek error on a 32bit machine with python 3.5.1 + python3-gdbm 3.5.1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `shelve` uses [gdbm](http://www.gnu.org.ua/software/gdbm/) (provided as `dbm.gnu` as default backend to store the serialized objects. The files created with gdbm depend on the architecture of the system and are therefore only usable on 32bit **or** 64bit systems.

There are some tools (`gdbmexport` or `gdbm_dump`) which allow you to convert the `gdbm` files, however, the workflow becomes error prone if you want to access the files from both systems on a regular basis.

Fortunately, python provides different backends: `dbm.gnu`, `dbm.ndbm` and `dbm.dumb`. The latter two are platform independent.

```
import shelve
import dbm
dbm._defaultmod = dbm.ndbm
db = shelve.open('somename')
```

The database with the above code can be used on 64bit and 32bit systems.

The default backend has to be set only when you create the file. `dbm` checks the file type of your database before opening and uses the correct backend.

Please note that the above code changes the default dbm for the whole python process. Another component might break if it relies on `gdbm` being the default.